# Map disappears after using Natural Earth projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a world map using the WGS 84 projection. I can reproject it as Miller, Robinson, or other projections, but when I use Natural Earth I or II, the map disappears. I'm applying this through Project > Properties > CRS. What am I doing wrong? Using QGIS 3.20 on a Mac.

It's a shapefile. I've attached images of the before and after I apply the change. I've tried all of the Natural Earth choices, and I get the same result.[image]

[image]

I've added a screenshot of the CRS dialog before applying the transformation. After I apply it, the main window is blank. If I Ziim to Layer, the window remains blank.

[image]

Comment: In which format your world map is, is it a shapefile or WMS? Can you please add some additional information as well as graphics. Are you using *'World_Natural_Earth'* or *'Sphere_Natural_Earth'*?

Comment: Did you right-click on the layer / Zoom to layer? What happens?

Comment: @Babel, nothings happens. It tried it also. There is no geometry shown even though the attribute table is full.

Comment: how did you transform the data?

Answer (score -1):

Your map disappears probably because of mismatch of project CRS and your map's CRS.

To reproject a layer into a different projection, you have to use one of the following:

- `Vector` > `Data Management Tools` > `Reproject Layer...`
- `Raster` > `Projections` > `Warp (Reproject)...`

Comment: No, this is QGIS, not ArcMap. QGIS has on the fly reprojection of layers to the project CRS

Comment: @bugmenot123 Having worked with a lot of layers in QGIS, I don't think so.

Comment: Are you using QGIS 2.x or something ?